# Insert into table using result set of dual query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, `edgar_t100` and which is a table of one column, named ID. I need it to have 100 rows where each row/column intersection is just the number of the row. Obviously I don't want to do this by writing insert clauses, so I thought about using the `dual` table from Oracle.

If I do, `select rownum as ID from dual connect by rownum <= 100`, then I get a nice table that captures exactly what I want.

Is there a way to do something like the following:

`insert into edgar_t100 values (select rownum as ID from dual connect by rownum <= 100)` 
(Obviously that doesn't work and I want to do this using SQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
insert into edgar_t100 (col1) 
select rownum as ID 
from dual 
connect by rownum <= 100
```

Comment: Whoa awesome, it works! But any reason why I didn't have to do `values` or put the `select` query in parenthesis?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Because it's not validate oracle's insert syntax :)