# MYSQL INSERT query based on SELECT query with LIMIT restrictions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-select

SELECT query

```
SELECT a. * , d.agent_id, COUNT( d.driver_id ) AS `noofdrivers`
                                      FROM ta_agent a, ta_drivers d
                                      WHERE a.agent_id = d.agent_id
                                      AND a.agent_id = ".$agent_id."
                                      GROUP BY a.agent_id
```

SELECT query returns this below records

```
agent_id  agent_name company_name  pricing_plan  noofdrivers
--------  ----------  -----------  ------------  -----------
    3         CCC           ZZZ          8499       2
    2         BBB           YYY          3499       3
```

DRIVER DB TABLE

```
agent_id  driver_id   driver_name
--------  ----------  -----------
2         1           EEE
2         2           FFF
2         3           GGG
1         4           HHH
3         5           III
3         6           JJJ
```

how do I INSERT the records based on above SELECT query results. if `pricing_plan` is 3499 `agent_id` 2 can add only 5 drivers. Now, `agent_id` 2 have 3 drivers. So, still he can add 2 drivers only. How to do this limit restriction in mysql query?

Comment: Should we use a statement level trigger for this?

Comment: Where do you want to insert? which table?

Comment: Can you give examples of what you would want to happen when (1) an agent has X empty spaces and inserts <X items, (2) X empty spaces and inserts X items, (3) X empty spaces and inserts >X items?

Comment: @ArdiGoxhaj : INSERT into driver_table

Comment: @MinhD : i don't know about statement level trigger. if you have any solution provide me

Comment: @DanielRenshaw : eg: agentid 2 have 3 drivers and agentid 2 pricing plan is 3499. if pricing plan is 3499 agentid 2 can add 5 drivers only. if he add 6th driver it won't insert in database. some alert will shown to user. got it ?

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223656/oracle-how-to-force-user-to-insert-multiple-row). In this case, the user want to limit a hotel room booking system. Min 3 and max 5 people can book into 1 room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
insert into driver(driver_id, agent_id, driver_name)
   select ins.driver_id, ins.agent_id, ins.driver_name
   from (select 7 as driver_id, 2 as agent_id, 'KKK' as driver_name) ins
   where (select count(*) 
      from driver d, agent a
      where d.agent_id=a.agent_id and a.agent_id=ins.agent_id and a.pricing_plan=3499)<5;
```

In given query, you'l have to place variables `$driver_id`, `$agent_id` and `$driver_name` for values `7`, `2` and `'KKK'` respectively.

so, it will look like,

```
$sql="insert into driver(driver_id, agent_id, driver_name)
   select ins.driver_id, ins.agent_id, ins.driver_name
   from (select $driver_id as driver_id, $agent_id as agent_id, $driver_name as driver_name) ins
   where (select count(*) 
      from driver d, agent a
      where d.agent_id=a.agent_id and a.agent_id=ins.agent_id and a.pricing_plan=3499)<5";
```

Here is **[DEMO SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10b9e4/3)**

Comment: how to insert the values into multiple tables with this query 
`insert into ta_drivers(driver_id, agent_id, driver_name)
insert into ta_vehicles(driver_id, vehicle_name, registration_number)
   select ins.driver_id, ins.agent_id, ins.driver_name, ins.driver_id, ins.vehicle_name, ins.registration_number
   from (select 7 as driver_id, 4 as agent_id, 'KKK' as driver_name, 'LENOVA' as vehicle_name, 'TN 05' as registration_number) as ins
   where (select count(*) 
          from ta_drivers d, ta_agent a
          where d.agent_id=a.agent_id and a.agent_id=ins.agent_id and a.pricing_plan=1799)<5;`

Comment: This wasn't mentioned before. :P Btw you can't insert to multiple tables using one query, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
insert into ta_drivers(agent_id, driver_id, driver_name) SELECT (agent_id, driver_id, driver_name) FROM dual where ((SELECT a. * , d.agent_id, COUNT( d.driver_id ) AS `noofdrivers`
                                  FROM ta_agent a, ta_drivers d
                                  WHERE a.agent_id = d.agent_id
                                  AND pricing_plan=3499 and a.agent_id = ".$agent_id."
                                  GROUP BY a.agent_id)<5);
```

You have to check the query because is not OK. but in theory:

```
insert into table select from dual where ((select count(*) condition) <5);
```

Comment: you clould check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584541/mysql-insert-into-with-dual-condition-for-if-not-exist or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728058/insert-into-table-using-result-set-of-dual-query